# db->query LIKE statement not functioning correctly

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am using joomla and encounter a small issue. In one of my db query I have a like statement as per below.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('a.*,b.category_name')
        ->from('#__carlist AS a')
        ->innerJoin('#__categories AS b ON b.id = a.category_id');

if ($name != '') {
$query->where("a.db_name like '%" . $name . "%'");
}

$db->setQuery($query);
$rows =  $db->loadObjectList();
```

The issue is that when I do a search from my search box, the result is abit different from using normal sql.

Where is wrong.
e.g if I search for 'hello me' the system will return no result. if I search for 'one' it will return result. In the DB there is really 'hello me' in it. Whenever I search for a string two words or more, the result will not return although in the DB it exist.

Does anyone know whats wrong with my coding?

Comment: Show us all of the code, not just that one statement.

Comment: My Andy the whole code works, only this portion have a slight problem that why i only put in this line of code.

Comment: Is there a way to echo the SQL statement that results from your query building statements? if so, echo it and look for errors there.

Comment: I don't understand your quoting ... what I usualy do is this, `$namelike = '%'.$name.'%';`  then $db->quote($name) ... you should really clean up the quong anyway you are not using backticks where you should.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is like that:

```
  a.db_name like '%hello me%'  // in the end should be like that
```

you have to echo your query and see if it looks like that. you'll have to make the query to look more like:

```
  Like '%hello%me%'
```

or split the two words to be

```
  Like '%hello%' or like '%me%'
```

you can also try with full text search

```
  MATCH( a.db_name) AGAINST ('hello me' in BOOLEAN MODE)
```